# Why I can't send a push notification using the Appcelerator REST API in C#?

Tags: c#, push-notification, appcelerator, restsharp

I'm trying to send a notify alert to all the devices subscribed to my channel through the RestSharp API for C#. This is how my code looks like:

```
    public void SendPush()
    {
        try
        {

            var client = new RestClient(" https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com");
            var request = new RestRequest("/v1/push_notification/notify.json?key=appkey", Method.POST)
            {
                RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
            };
            request.AddBody(new
            {
                channel = "alert", payload = new { title = "notificación", badge = 1, alert = "alerta: proximo arribo de sismo a la ciudad de mexico", sound = "default" }
            });
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;
            Debug.WriteLine(content);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Message " + ex.Message + " \n Inner Exception " + ex.InnerException + " \n Stack Trace" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

The response I get is the following:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "status": "fail",
    "code": 401,
   "cc_code": 1000,
   "message": "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
  }
}
```

Why is it asking me to login? All what I'm trying to do is to send a notify message to the devices.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I was able to login, store the connection information into a CookieContainer and send the notification request, but I can't send the payload parameter as an object.

This is how my new Login function looks like:

```
    public void Login()
    {
        client = new RestClient("https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com");
        client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        request = new RestRequest("/v1/users/login.json?key={appkey}", Method.POST)
        {
            RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
        };
        request.AddUrlSegment("appkey", "key");
        request.AddBody(new
        {
            login = "user",
            password = "pass"
        });
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content;
        Debug.WriteLine(content);
        SendPush();
    }
```

This is how my SendPush function looks like now:

```
    public void SendPush()
    {
        try
        {
            client.BaseUrl = "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com";
            request.Resource = "/v1/push_notification/notify.json?key={appkey}";
            request.Method = Method.POST;
            request.AddUrlSegment("appkey", "key");


            request.AddParameter("channel", "alert");
            request.AddParameter("payload", new
                {
                  title = "notification", 
                  badge = 1, 
                  alert = "Warning", 
                  sound = "default" 
                });
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;
            Debug.WriteLine(content);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Message " + ex.Message + " \n Inner Exception " + ex.InnerException + " \n Stack Trace" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to send an object as a parameter but it doesn't seem to be valid, I don't know why. If I just try to send something like this:

```
            request.AddParameter("payload", "Warning");
```

I get a response from the Appcelerator API, but not the behavior I want to in the mobile app, since the payload is missing several properties.

How should I send that object as a parameter with RestSharp? Or RestSharp doesn't allow that? What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way to do this. First I have to login and save the session in a CookieContainer like this:

```
    public void Login()
    {
        client = new RestClient("https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com");
        client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        request = new RestRequest("/v1/users/login.json?key={appkey}", Method.POST)
        {
            RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
        };
        request.AddUrlSegment("appkey", "key");
        request.AddBody(new
        {
            login = "user",
            password = "pass"
        });
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        SendPush();
    }
```

Then I make a call to my SendPush method which looks like this now:

```
    public void SendPush()
    {
        try
        {
            client.BaseUrl = "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com";
            request.Resource = "/v1/push_notification/notify.json?key={appkey}";
            request.Method = Method.POST;
            request.AddUrlSegment("appkey", "key");

            request.AddParameter("channel", "alert");
            request.AddParameter("payload", "{ \"title\" : \"notificación\", \"badge\" : 1, \"alert\" : \"alerta: Sismo detectado en: " + direccion + " proximo arribo de sismo a la ciudad de mexico\", \"sound\" : \"default\"}");
            var response = client.Execute(request);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Message " + ex.Message + " \n Inner Exception " + ex.InnerException + " \n Stack Trace" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

I was having trouble sending the payload object in the AddBody method, so I decided to send it as a string with AddParameter and it worked with no problem, this can be done too using the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) or JsonConverter from [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). Hope it helps other people.

Comment: I am trying the same code, but it is not working. Even after providing the correct username and password, it gives an error that either of them is incorrect. I can login into dashboard and access the application from there. Any idea as to why I am getting this error?

Comment: I haven't work with Appcelerator for some time, but I guess when you say you can login into the Dashboard, you're refering to the credentials of the Appcelerator user, not a user in your Users collection. Don't use your Appcelerator credentials to login, you need to use a user you have created in your Users collections, those are the ones you want to login into your app. I'll check later but this should be your problem.

Comment: Ok. But after I login into the dashboard, I can go to the Arrow panel and then I can send push messages to the registered devices. I am using the token method in the client side.

Comment: Oh it seems I misread the stituation, I confused user login with the login to use the Appcelerator services, sorry it's been some time since I used Appcelerator. Can you provide me with the response from the login request?

Comment: Following is the response I am getting. Request returned with HTTP status code 401 Invalid email/username or password. I have triple checked the username and password. I am able to login into dashboard.appcelerator.com using it.

Comment: The answer to my above query is posted here ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354975/appcelerator-using-rest-api.

Comment: so it was the credentials, always double check the credentials you use and the appkey, those are most common problems when using push notifications

Comment: I'm able to successful login and also connection, but it gives error in sendpush() response, it is 422 syntax error .... this is request api log from appcelerator account /v1/push_notification/notify.json?&channel=demo_alert&key=bjZndUjvVoL233F01jyrfcgesGTABmVb&payload={'title' :'notificación','alert' : 'HIgh'}

Comment: I made the changes that the user was not admin - so i made the user as admin and then I'm now receiving 400 error

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a valid app key

```
var myAppKey = "WhateverYourAppKeyIs";
var request = new RestRequest("/v1/push_notification/notify.json?key=" + myAppKey , Method.POST)
```

Comment: I'm doing that, I've tried with both production and development key and it didn't worked.

Comment: If that is the case then you'll probably need to contact appcelerator support.  The problem doesn't appear to be in your code from what I can tell.

Comment: check my edited question, it seems I had to login in the end and store the info into a CookieContainer, but I'm not able to send an object as a parameter, any ideas?

Comment: I think you want to call AddBody instead of AddParameter for the payload but I'm not that familiar with RestSharp.  I've always just used HttpWebRequest or in .NET 4.5 HttpClient