# Appcelerator - Using REST API

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow

I am calling the following curl command, but it is always returning me invalid username/password.

```
curl -F "login=myemailAddress" -F "password=myPassword" "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/users/login.json?key=<API_KEY>"
```

I am using the key defined in TiApp.xml as acs-api-key-production. Now if I use the same username and password and login through dashboard.appcelerator.com, then I am able to do so.

Can someone please point out as to what issue is this. I am doing a similar implementation in C#, which too is returning the same invalid username/password error.

Comment: Can anyone confirm, as to whether do I need to provide the credentials for the appcelerator dashboard login or is there any other credential I need to provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username and password should not be from your AppC account, but from an (admin) user you create at:

```
https://platform.appcelerator.com/#/api/data/<GUID>/data.next/user
```

In the dashboard, navigate to your ArrowDB app > Manage Data > Users > Create User. There should already be an admin user you can use.

Comment: Thanks Fokke. I created a new admin user and now I am getting back a proper response using the curl command. Now I need to make the changes in C# code and test it.